# How to directly compare a first and second element in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Quick Question, I'm trying to print a new line every time a character from an char array is NOT the subsequent character. An example being if text[i] is 'a' and text[i + 1] is NOT 'b', then printf("\n");

an example I/O would be:

```
 input: "abk123@XY"
 output: ab
         123
         XY
```

output right now  is:

```
\n
\n
\n
```

This is the current code I have now:

```
void printNext(const char *t){
 //variable declerations 
 int i;

 for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++){

   if(t[i] != t[i + 1])//line in question, which isn't working 
      printf("\n");
    else if(t[i] >= '0' &&  t[i] <= '9')
        printf("%c",t[i]);
     else if (t[i] >= 'A'  && t[i] <= 'Z' )
          printf("%c",t[i]);
        else if(t[i] >= 'a'  && t[i] <= 'z')
            printf("%c",t[i]);


        }//end for

}//end printNext
```

Main function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void printNext(const char *);

int main(void){

  const char t[40] = "abk123@XY";

   printf("the original sequence of strings is: %s\n", text);
   printf("new string is: \n");
   printNext(t);


 }
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. If your program does not work then please state the exact input, expected output and actual output. Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: how about change the if statement to if(t[i] + 1 != t[i+1])?

Comment: @minigeek Where is the actual output or specific question? All we have is "not working".

Comment: @CMcorpse check the solution :)

Comment: what do you mean with _each time a character from an array is NOT the subsequent character_?  In your question you are trying *only* to insert `\n` chars, so where did the `k` and `@` go?  What's the exact requirements of your problem, as *none* of the characters you present as input are the next character, so you should get as many `\n` chars as input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove else from every condition. Else if is checked only if 'if' fails.but you want next condition to be checked though, change the sequence of checking condition as well.

```
for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++){ 
     if(t[i] >= '0' &&  t[i] <= '9' )
          printf("%c",t[i]);
     if (t[i] >= 'A'  && t[i] <= 'Z' )
          printf("%c",t[i]);
     if(t[i] >= 'a'  && t[i] <= 'z')
          printf("%c",t[i]);
     if(t[i] + 1 != t[i + 1]) 
          printf("\n");
 }//end for
```

Changes in main

```
int main(){
     const char t[80] = "abk123@XY";
     printf("the original sequence of strings is: %s\n", t);
     printf("new string is: \n");
     printNext(t);       
     return 0; 

}
```

Comment: hmm, that doesn't appear to work, the output for this code is:   a \n b \n k \n 1 \n 2 \n 3\n \n X \n Y

Comment: @CMcorpse yeah you said u want new line after every input

Comment: no just when a character is not the subsequent character.

Comment: @CMcorpse changed if condition..now check again

Comment: nope, that edit gives me a \n b \n k12 \n 3 \n X \n Y

Comment: @CMcorpse can you post main function..i can test

Comment: @BLUEPIXY btw code is supposed to print k as it is also a character from atoz but on new line individually and since there is no element after k 123 is on next line. Which my code does anyways..op forgot to mention print of k in his output :p.. intro of question says new line only after non consecutive char

Comment: The OP's sample seems not to allow one letter as a subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool sameKindAndSeq(unsigned char a, unsigned char b){
    if(!a || !b || a + 1 != b)
        return false;
    if(islower(a))
        return islower(b);
    if(isupper(a))
        return isupper(b);
    if(isdigit(a))
        return isdigit(b);
    return false;
}

void printNext(const char *t){
    bool first = true;//flag of top of sequence of same kind
    for(; *t; ++t){
        if(first){
            if(sameKindAndSeq(*t, t[1])){
                putchar(*t);
                first = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(sameKindAndSeq(t[-1], *t)){
                putchar(*t);
            }
            if(!sameKindAndSeq(*t, t[1])){
                putchar('\n');
                first = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    printNext("abk123@XY");
}
```

Comment: @minigeek What do you want to say?

Comment: I haven't seen booleans in c `bool`  thanx for it..can we use it like in java

Comment: @minigeek `bool` can be used since  C99 ( in `<stdbool.h>` )

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more readable version of @minigeek's answer:

```
void printNext(const char *t)
{
    int i;
    int isdigit(int);
    int isupper(int);
    int islower(int);

    for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (isdigit(t[i]))
            printf("%c",t[i]);
        if (isupper(t[i]))
            printf("%c",t[i]);
        if(islower(t[i]))
            printf("%c",t[i]);
        if(t[i] + 1 != t[i + 1])
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```